# Is it required for NDIS lwf(protocol) driver to sign digital signature use in windows?

Tags: c, windows, driver, device-driver, ndis

I try to develope NDIS lwf driver for filtering a specific packet.

I succeeded to run the driver I developed in windows 10 which is test mode for debugging.

I changed window test mode to normal mode and then run the driver in window which is not test mode. but the driver is not loaded.

For checking the driver, I run the script(exe) ‘sc query ndis driver’ in cmd.exe. the script(exe) returns exit code 577.

The driver is build by test signing. and I installed the driver to use netcfg API in bindview sample in window driver samples.

The bindview sample use SetupCopyOEMInf function and netcfg Install function for installing network driver. I try to copy my NDIS lwf driver(test sign) files to system driver(INF) folder by using SetupCopyOEMInf. But SetupCopyOEMInf return FALSE and GetLastError return 0xe0000277.

I checked the setupapi dev log in c:/window/INF directory. the log file details error description “the driver is not signed digital signature”.

So I forcibly copied the driver inf and cat file in c:/window/INF directory. and then I installed the driver by calling netcfg Install function. the driver which installed using the above the way normally work in windows 10 which is test mode and kernel debugging. but the driver not work in windows 10 which is not test mode(is normal mode).

I have a few questions.

1. Do only NDIS lwf(protocol) driver which signed a digital signature work in windows 10 which is not test mode?
2. Is there a way to work the test signing driver in windows 10 which is not test mode?
3. Is there a way to sign digital signature to NDIS lwf(protocol) driver for free?

Answer (score 1):

1. Do only NDIS lwf(protocol) driver which signed a digital signature work in windows 10 which is not test mode?

***A: Yes we need to have proper signed driver to run in windows 10 without test mode. Also it needs to be signed EV Certificate (Extended Validation certificate) ***

2. Is there a way to work the test signing driver in windows 10 which is not test mode?

***A: No. Sorry there isn't. Windows strictly disallow drivers without sign for security purpose.***

3. Is there a way to sign digital signature to NDIS lwf(protocol) driver for free?

***A: No.There is not way to sign windows driver for free. Specially kernel mode drivers.***